# За неимением гербовой пишут на простой

Tags: орфоэпия, языковые-изменения

В фильме "Щит и меч" Лансдорф произносит эту пословицу с ударением на последний слог в слове *гербовой.* Так разве правильно? Или это старая норма?

Answer (score 1):

Герб**о**вый — это [устаревший вариант](https://xn--80acgfbsl1azdqr.xn--p1ai/news/326-kak-pravilno-gerbovyy-ili-gerbovyy).

Comment: При чём тут *герб**о**вый?* Речь о *гербов**о**м.*

Comment: Артем, Резниченко пишет, что ударение имело разные варианты (гербОвый, гербовОй), но в настоящий момент правильным считается гЕрбовый. Меня всегда интересовало, почему меняются нормы ударения. В данном случае я могу предположить, что смысловые оттенки слова тоже меняются, а вы как думаете? Вот у Пушкина: "Под гЕрбовой моей печатью Я кипу грамот сохранил". Хотя здесь по записи слова ударение не определишь... Но Резниченко так считает.

Comment: Возможно, и меняются действительно оттенки. А у Пушкина я бы поставил ударение тоже на конец слова, тем более что на соответствующее ему А в *грамот* акцент заметный.